# Home page is not cached

Tags: magento, varnish

I'm using the following Varnish 3.0.5 configuration for Magento 1.9.2.4 from the Nexcessnet Turpentine extension:

```
## Custom C Code

C{
    // @source app/code/community/Nexcessnet/Turpentine/misc/uuid.c
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <pthread.h>

    static pthread_mutex_t lrand_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

    void generate_uuid(char* buf) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lrand_mutex);
        long a = lrand48();
        long b = lrand48();
        long c = lrand48();
        long d = lrand48();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lrand_mutex);
        // SID must match this regex for Kount compat /^\w{1,32}$/
        sprintf(buf, "frontend=%08lx%04lx%04lx%04lx%04lx%08lx",
            a,
            b & 0xffff,
            (b & ((long)0x0fff0000) >> 16) | 0x4000,
            (c & 0x0fff) | 0x8000,
            (c & (long)0xffff0000) >> 16,
            d
        );
        return;
    }

}C

## Imports

import std;

## Backends

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "80";
   .first_byte_timeout = 300s;
   .between_bytes_timeout = 300s;
}

backend admin {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "80";
   .first_byte_timeout = 21600s;
   .between_bytes_timeout = 21600s;
}

## ACLs

acl crawler_acl {
    "127.0.0.1";
}

## Varnish Subroutines

sub vcl_recv {

    # this always needs to be done so it's up at the top
    if (req.restarts == 0) {
        if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
                req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
        }
    }

    if(false) {
        # save the unmodified url
        set req.http.X-Varnish-Origin-Url = req.url;
    }

    # Normalize request data before potentially sending things off to the
    # backend. This ensures all request types get the same information, most
    # notably POST requests getting a normalized user agent string to empower
    # adaptive designs.
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } else if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unknown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    # we test this here instead of inside the url base regex section
    # so we can disable caching for the entire site if needed
    if (!true || req.http.Authorization ||
        req.request !~ "^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS)$" ||
        req.http.Cookie ~ "varnish_bypass=1") {
        if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/de/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?administration") {
            set req.backend = admin;
        }
        return (pipe);
    }

    # remove double slashes from the URL, for higher cache hit rate
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "([^:])//+", "\1/");

    # check if the request is for part of magento
    if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/de/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?") {
        # set this so Turpentine can see the request passed through Varnish
        set req.http.X-Turpentine-Secret-Handshake = "1";
        # use the special admin backend and pipe if it's for the admin section
        if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/de/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?administration") {
            set req.backend = admin;
            return (pipe);
        }
        if (req.http.Cookie ~ "\bcurrency=") {
            set req.http.X-Varnish-Currency = regsub(
                req.http.Cookie, ".*\bcurrency=([^;]*).*", "\1");
        }
        if (req.http.Cookie ~ "\bstore=") {
            set req.http.X-Varnish-Store = regsub(
                req.http.Cookie, ".*\bstore=([^;]*).*", "\1");
        }
        # looks like an ESI request, add some extra vars for further processing
        if (req.url ~ "/turpentine/esi/get(?:Block|FormKey)/") {
            set req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method = regsub(
                req.url, ".*/method/(\w+)/.*", "\1");
            set req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access = regsub(
                req.url, ".*/access/(\w+)/.*", "\1");

            # throw a forbidden error if debugging is off and a esi block is
            # requested by the user (does not apply to ajax blocks)
            if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "esi" && req.esi_level == 0 &&
                    !(false || client.ip ~ debug_acl)) {
                error 403 "External ESI requests are not allowed";
            }
        }

        # no frontend cookie was sent to us AND this is not an ESI or AJAX call
        if (req.http.Cookie !~ "frontend=" && !req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method) {
            if (client.ip ~ crawler_acl ||
                    req.http.User-Agent ~ "^(?:ApacheBench/.*|.*Googlebot.*|JoeDog/.*Siege.*|magespeedtest\.com|Nexcessnet_Turpentine/.*)$") {
                # it's a crawler, give it a fake cookie
                set req.http.Cookie = "frontend=crawler-session";
            } else {
                # it's a real user, make up a new session for them
                return (pipe);
            }
        }
        if (true &&
                req.url ~ ".*\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|swf)(?=\?|&|$)") {
            # don't need cookies for static assets
            unset req.http.Cookie;
            unset req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session;
            set req.http.X-Varnish-Static = 1;
            return (lookup);
        }
        # this doesn't need a enable_url_excludes because we can be reasonably
        # certain that cron.php at least will always be in it, so it will
        # never be empty
        if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/de/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?(?:administration|api|cron\.php)" ||
                # user switched stores. we pipe this instead of passing below because
                # switching stores doesn't redirect (302), just acts like a link to
                # another page (200) so the Set-Cookie header would be removed
                req.url ~ "\?.*__from_store=") {
            return (pipe);
        }
        if (true &&
                req.url ~ "(?:[?&](?:__SID|XDEBUG_PROFILE)(?=[&=]|$))") {
            # TODO: should this be pass or pipe?
            return (pass);
        }
        if (true && req.url ~ "[?&](utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|utm_term|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") {
            # Strip out Ignored GET parameters
            set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)?|&)(?:utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|utm_term|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=[^&]+", "\1");
            set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)&|\?$)", "\1");
        }

        if(false) {
            set req.http.X-Varnish-Cache-Url = req.url;
            set req.url = req.http.X-Varnish-Origin-Url;
            unset req.http.X-Varnish-Origin-Url;
        }

        # everything else checks out, try and pull from the cache
        return (lookup);
    }
    # else it's not part of magento so do default handling (doesn't help
    # things underneath magento but we can't detect that)
}

sub vcl_pipe {
    # since we're not going to do any stuff to the response we pretend the
    # request didn't pass through Varnish
    unset bereq.http.X-Turpentine-Secret-Handshake;
    set bereq.http.Connection = "close";
}

sub vcl_hash {
    # For static files we keep the hash simple and don't add the domain.
    # This saves memory when a static file is used on multiple domains.
    if (true && req.http.X-Varnish-Static) {
        hash_data(req.url);
        if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
            # make sure we give back the right encoding
            hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding);
        }
        return (hash);
    }

    if(false && req.http.X-Varnish-Cache-Url) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Varnish-Cache-Url);
    } else {
        hash_data(req.url);
    }
    if (req.http.Host) {
        hash_data(req.http.Host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }
    hash_data(req.http.Ssl-Offloaded);
    if (req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent);
    }
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        # make sure we give back the right encoding
        hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding);
    }
    if (req.http.X-Varnish-Store || req.http.X-Varnish-Currency) {
        # make sure data is for the right store and currency based on the *store*
        # and *currency* cookies
        hash_data("s=" + req.http.X-Varnish-Store + "&c=" + req.http.X-Varnish-Currency);
    }

    if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private" &&
            req.http.Cookie ~ "frontend=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^.*?frontend=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "customer_group" &&
            req.http.Cookie ~ "customer_group=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^.*?customer_group=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_fetch {
    # set the grace period
    set req.grace = 15s;

    # Store the URL in the response object, to be able to do lurker friendly bans later
    set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Host = req.http.host;
    set beresp.http.X-Varnish-URL = req.url;

    # if it's part of magento...
    if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/de/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?") {
        # we handle the Vary stuff ourselves for now, we'll want to actually
        # use this eventually for compatibility with downstream proxies
        # TODO: only remove the User-Agent field from this if it exists
        unset beresp.http.Vary;
        # we pretty much always want to do this
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;

        if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
            # pass anything that isn't a 200 or 404
            set beresp.ttl = 15s;
            return (hit_for_pass);
        } else {
            # if Magento sent us a Set-Cookie header, we'll put it somewhere
            # else for now
            if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) {
                set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Set-Cookie = beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
                unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
            }
            # we'll set our own cache headers if we need them
            unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
            unset beresp.http.Expires;
            unset beresp.http.Pragma;
            unset beresp.http.Cache;
            unset beresp.http.Age;

            if (beresp.http.X-Turpentine-Esi == "1") {
                set beresp.do_esi = true;
            }
            if (beresp.http.X-Turpentine-Cache == "0") {
                set beresp.ttl = 15s;
                return (hit_for_pass);
            } else {
                if (true &&
                        bereq.url ~ ".*\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|swf)(?=\?|&|$)") {
                    # it's a static asset
                    set beresp.ttl = 28800s;
                    set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=28800";
                } elseif (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method) {
                    # it's a ESI request
                    if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private" &&
                            req.http.Cookie ~ "frontend=") {
                        # set this header so we can ban by session from Turpentine
                        set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Session = regsub(req.http.Cookie,
                            "^.*?frontend=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1");
                    }
                    if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "ajax" &&
                            req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "public") {
                        set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=" + regsub(
                            req.url, ".*/ttl/(\d+)/.*", "\1");
                    }
                    set beresp.ttl = std.duration(
                        regsub(
                            req.url, ".*/ttl/(\d+)/.*", "\1s"),
                        300s);
                    if (beresp.ttl == 0s) {
                        # this is probably faster than bothering with 0 ttl
                        # cache objects
                        set beresp.ttl = 15s;
                        return (hit_for_pass);
                    }
                } else {
                    set beresp.ttl = 3600s;
                }
            }
        }
        # we've done what we need to, send to the client
        return (deliver);
    }
    # else it's not part of Magento so use the default Varnish handling
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session) {
        # need to set the set-cookie header since we just made it out of thin air
        # call generate_session_expires;
        # call generate_session_expires
        set resp.http.Set-Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session +
            "; expires=" + resp.http.X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires + "; path=/";
        if (req.http.Host) {
            if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "^(?:ApacheBench/.*|.*Googlebot.*|JoeDog/.*Siege.*|magespeedtest\.com|Nexcessnet_Turpentine/.*)$") {
                # it's a crawler, no need to share cookies
                set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie +
                "; domain=" + regsub(req.http.Host, ":\d+$", "");
            } else {
                # it's a real user, allow sharing of cookies between stores
                if(req.http.Host ~ "") {
                    set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie +
                    "; domain=";
                } else {
                    set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie +
                    "; domain=" + regsub(req.http.Host, ":\d+$", "");
                }
            }
        }
        set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie + "; httponly";
        unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires;
    }
    if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "ajax" && req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private") {
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-cache";
    }
    if (false || client.ip ~ debug_acl) {
        # debugging is on, give some extra info
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Hits = obj.hits;
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method = req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method;
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access = req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access;
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Currency = req.http.X-Varnish-Currency;
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Store = req.http.X-Varnish-Store;
    } else {
        # remove Varnish fingerprints
        unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
        unset resp.http.Via;
        unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
        unset resp.http.Server;
        unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Cache;
        unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Esi;
        unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Flush-Events;
        unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Block;
        unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Session;
        unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Host;
        unset resp.http.X-Varnish-URL;
        # this header indicates the session that originally generated a cached
        # page. it *must* not be sent to a client in production with lax
        # session validation or that session can be hijacked
        unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Set-Cookie;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except the home page (http://www.my-shop.test/) gets never cached by varnish. Has anybody a hint for me how I could fix that?

Comment: That's unusual... are you sure the other pages are getting served from the cache? Have you tried reloading the home page? By default the first request gets passed through to Magento.

Comment: @AricWatson Sure I've tested this! ;) When take a look into the code you will see regular expression like `(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/de/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)` and in this the path to the home page is not included. But when I change this regular expressions to `(/|/media/|/skin/|/js/|/de/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)` the home page gets cached but the backend is not working correctly.

Comment: @witrin I am seeing similar issue with redis. Did you find solution?